# Update Json file and send data to php

Tags: php, json

I would like to modify a JSON file but when I see the result file I find that the modifications are not done, the content still the same. Here is my function code:

```
...
var res=null;
var data;

function reqAjax(){
    $.getJSON( "my_data.json", function(data) {     
          $.each( data.features, function( key, val ) {
            $.each( val.geometry.coordinates, function( key2, val2 ) {
                //translate gps coords in WGS84
                res = proj4(source,dest,val2);
                val2 = res;
            });
          });

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'modify_json.php',
            data: 'data='+ $.toJSON(data),
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(reponse){ 
                alert(reponse);
            },
            error: function(objet,status,error){console.log(objet);console.log(status);console.log(error);alert('Erreur');}

        });

    });

}
</script>
```

Here is an extract of the beginning of my json file :

```
{"name":"Générique00","type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties": "name":"EPSG:3943"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[1572278.0427,2265904.7471],[1572297.3459,2265927.3032],[1572345.662,2266087.3337],[1572402.9689,2266282.1927],[1572449.9837,2266423.1244],[1572460.9373,2266460.3007],[1572486.8947,2266547.9981],[1572493.0022,2266572.4946]]},"properties":{"obs_gestion":"Grand Toulouse","Nom_voie":"rue gamelin","obs_crea":"2011","Commune":"Toulouse","obs_type":"bandes","Longueur_m":704,"Carte_RV":"0","code_insee":"31555","obs_entre":0,"Pole":2,"Revetement":"enrobe","Mot_directeur":"GAMELIN","type":"RC","Carte_velo":"Bandes cyclables ou couloir bus","Section":"vauquelin - mermoz"}},...
```

This is my modify_json.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){


    file_put_contents('test2.json', ($_POST['data']));

}
```

Do you have any idea of what's wrong?
Any suggestion will be welcome :)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are writing your data to a different file than you are reading from.  Is that your intent? Also, do you really want people to be able to change files on your server in such an insecure fashion?

Comment: For the moment i'm just making tests because i have not finish to code my app yet. In the final version I would like a registered user to upload these file and the it would be modified by this app into WGS84 coords.

Answer (score 0):

update your javascript to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'modify_json.php',
    data: { newData: $.toJSON(data) },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(reponse){ 
        alert(reponse);
    },
    error: function(objet,status,error){console.log(objet);console.log(status);console.log(error);alert('Erreur');}
});
```

and update your PHP to:

```
if (isset($_POST['newdata'])){
    file_put_contents('test2.json', $_POST['newData']);
}
```

Comment: As the jQuery documentation says, `data` can be a `String` or `PlainObject`. Object will be parsed to string anyway so your code does not make any difference.

Comment: I tried it but modification are still not done in the new file. Maybe it is a problem with my javascript/jquery code.  Thanks for your help!